# When this is clicked, add a class to a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am coding my own website and I am using jQuery with it. But I'm a beginner with jQuery and I have a small question. I have in my HTML doc:

```
<ol class="steps">
            <li><span class="step">Het verkrijgen van uw wensen. </span><span class="stepText">In deze stap komen we tot een overeenstemming hoe de website eruit zal komen te zien. Dit zal te paard gaan met een of meerdere tekeningen, om een zo goed mogelijk beeld te krijgen van wat u wilt met uw website.</span>
            </li>
            <li><span class="step">De offerte. </span><span class="stepText">Hier krijgt u de offerte toegestuurd met alle bijkomende informatie.</span>
            </li>
</ol>
```

(This is a shortened version, I have it with 6 <li> tags, so give them all different classes isn't a great solution...)

What I now want to happen, is when e.g. the first span (class = step) is clicked, the span next to it (class = stepText) must have a new class. This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".step").click(function() {

        $(this).find($(".stepText"))addClass(".stepTextV");
        $(this).find($(".stepTextV"))removeClass(".stepText");

            // what I tried before: 
           $(".stepText", this).addClass(".stepTextV");
           $(".stepTextV", this).removeClass(".stepText");
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, 
Brent M.

Comment: You're missing `.` character before `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Comment: use `.next` instead of `.find`!

Comment: `.find()` is for finding child elements. `.stepText` is not a child of `.step`.

Comment: And the argument to `.find` should be a selector, not a jQuery object.

Comment: The `.` before `addClass` and `removeClass` is probably the most silly mistake I made today lol
<br>But still not working... with `.next` neither...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect that's all, plus next() is your friend here :) ....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".step").click(function() {
    $(".stepTextV").removeClass("stepTextV");
    $(this).next(".stepText").addClass("stepTextV"); //You might also consider toggleClass
  });
});
```

```css
.step {font-weight: bold; }
.stepTextV {background: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="steps">
  <li><span class="step">Het verkrijgen van uw wensen. </span><span class="stepText">In deze stap komen we tot een overeenstemming hoe de website eruit zal komen te zien. Dit zal te paard gaan met een of meerdere tekeningen, om een zo goed mogelijk beeld te krijgen van wat u wilt met uw website.</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="step">De offerte. </span><span class="stepText">Hier krijgt u de offerte toegestuurd met alle bijkomende informatie.</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You should add CSS to your snippet so you can see the effect of the addClass

Comment: @Barmar - haha I was literally just working on that! :)

Comment: pretty color :) I never think to use pink, I always go with boring green or blue.

Comment: Why is the last class without a `.`??

Comment: @Barmar haha, pink is always my quick highlight colour I don't know why. Doesn't clash with margin or padding in firebug I guess haha

Comment: @Brent - Which class Brent?

Comment: @mayersdesign the class `.addClass("stepTextV");`

Comment: @Brent That's ADDING a class you see, not targeting one. So we say find this thing which is a (".example") or ("#example") which jQuery realises then is a class or ID. But to ADD a class we just have to pass jQuery the name of the class we want ("example")

Comment: Thank you @mayersdesign! Now, one single question left: I want it now to be toggleled. I tried the `.toggleClass`, but that's just turning it on. I might use a `if-else` statement, but I don't know how to use those in jQuery...

Comment: @Brent, there you go. I edited my answer. Now it simply removes the class from any elements that already have it, before it adds the class. jQuery is very much an "obvious once you see it" language haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".step").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.step').children('.stepText').removeClass('stepTextV');
  $(this).children('.stepText').addClass('stepTextV');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".step").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".stepText")
            .addClass("stepTextV")
            .removeClass("stepText");
    });
});
```